# Issue with loading uniform vec/mat in openGL ES 3 on IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I am working on doing heavy linear algebra with GPU on IOS so I am trying out openGL ES 3.0. I started from [Bartosz Ciechanowski's toy code](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/01/05/exploring_gpgpu_on_ios/) to work out some general large-by-small matrix multiplication. I split the large one into vectors and use a set of uniform matrices to represent the smaller matrix. I have managed to input and output the vertex shaders, but cannot get the uniform matrices right as it always looks empty. Here is what I did:

In the vertex shader, I just copy over what I sent in the uniform vector:

```
uniform vec3 transMat0;
uniform vec3 transMat1;
in vec2 InV0;
out vec2 OutV0;
void main(){    
    OutV0 = vec2(transMat0.x,transMat1.y);
//    OutV0 = InV0+vec2(1.0,2.0); //this works
}
```

In the ObjC code, I declared the buffer content as global variables:

```
static GLfloat mat0Data[] = {1000.0,100.0,10.0,1.0,0.1,0.01};//outside methods
static GLfloat mat1Data[] = {1000.0,100.0,10.0,1.0,0.1,0.01};//outside methods
```

And at where I compile the shader and generate the program handle, I attach the buffer:

```
GLuint mat0 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "transMat0");
GLuint mat1 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "transMat1");
glUniform3fv(mat0, 1, &(mat0Data[0]));
glUniform3fv(mat1, 1, &(mat1Data[0]));
```

The output buffer just reads all 0. Just to prove everything else worked, I can get the correct result at the transform feedback when I used the commented line

```
OutV0 = InV0+vec2(1.0,2.0); //this works
```

So I have to doubt I missed something with the uniform vectors. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the values of `mat0` and `mat1`?

Comment: Are you calling `glUseProgram()` with the correct program before you call `glUniform3fv()`?

Comment: Yes Reto, it turned out to be the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Reto pointed out in the comment, I missed calling

```
glUseProgram()
```

With that added, I can get everything correct now.